# Python: How to increase count for a code every time a function is run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add a function to my project where initial it starts with zero and every time this function is run it increments by 1. The issue here is that I don't want it to reset to zero except if the database of the project is reset.

```
def serial_code():
    count = 0
    count += 1
    return count

print(serial_code())
```

Comment: There is no way. If you run your code and terminate your code and rerun it it will reset the variable count

Comment: Do you want the variable to always be something even if we terminate the program?

Comment: You probably need to store the count in the database.

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer yes I want it to be saved in the DB and next time the function is run it increments by 1

Comment: Create a global variable and increment it every time the code is run. Then when returning it you should put it ion the database

Comment: @A_K then you should check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 option and that option is to use file.

Create a new `.txt` file in your directory, let's call it `count.txt` and then put `0` into that file.

```py
def serial_code():
    called = True

    if called:
        count_file = open("count.txt", "r") # open file in read mode
        count = count_file.read() # read data 
        count_file.close() # close file

        count_file = open("count.txt", "w") # open file again but in write mode
        count = int(count) + 1 # increase the count value by add 1
        count_file.write(str(count)) # write count to file
        count_file.close() # close file

    return count
```

- First we open file in read mode to read data from the file which is `0` then
  assign 0 into `count` variable and close the file.
- Second, open file back again but in write mode this time (we do this because **write** mode will rewrite the whole content), then increase 1, write to file, and close file.

Now whenever you call the function the value inside file will increase by 1. 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 .....

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the `global`-keyword for the variable that should persist beyond the scope of the function. After being initialised once, the variable `i` in the following code is increased with every call to `f`:

```
i = 0
def f():
    global i
    i += 1
    
for _ in range(100):
    f()
    print(i)
```

Comment: does not address anything regarding database - using global is a possibility for local usage if it does not need to be persisted over runs of the script but still is a bad way to do it

Answer (score -1):

See your code that u declare the variable in the function itself that's why it always reset declare it outside. And make the variable global

```
count = 0
def serial_code():
    global count
    count += 1
    return count
print(serial_code())
```

Comment: does not address anything regarding database - using global is a possibility for local usage if it does not need to be persisted over runs of the script but still is a bad way to do it